# Remagnetizing a generator?

Tags: induction

https://www.hunker.com/12606720/how-to-remagnetize-an-electric-generator

Seems plausible (though I’m still skeptical) for a permanent magnet drill motor.  But is it true?

And if it is, would it also work for a motor in which the magnetism is produced by the power input?

Comment: That article has a great photo of a pump at the top.

Comment: That article appears to be ill advised near nonsense verging on garbage.  It's making a number of unverifiable assumptions in assuming the drill and generator are wired in such a way that spinning the drill will backfeed the output in such a way as to energise windings with DC and magnetise them.

Comment: Some generators or motors with self exciting windings rely on a small amount of residual magnetism or a few small permanent magnets to start the chain reaction that energises the field coils.  Normally when you talk about flashing a winding, it is providing a burst of field and therefore power to start it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the article is nonsense.  electric drills have universal motors, and universal motors don't generate electricity when spun. also the speed control in the driven drill will not pass electric energy backwards.